# How to get the scopes of the running task?

Tags: sbt

I want to get the project and configuration axis from within the task. For example, considering the following task:

```
myTask := {
  val project = ?
  val configuration = ?
  val key = ?
  println(s"project: $project")
  println(s"configuration: $configuration")
  println(s"key: $key")
}
```

If I run the task like this,

```
> myModule/myConfig:myTask
```

it should print

```
project: myModule
configuration: myConfig
key: myTask
```

Answer (score 0):

My partial solution in `build.sbt` would be as follows:

```
lazy val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("Prints axes of its execution")

lazy val myTaskSetting = myTask := {
  val project = thisProject.value.id
  val cfg = configuration.?.value
  val key = myTask.key.label
  println(s"project: $project")
  println(s"configuration: $cfg")
  println(s"key: $key")
}

myTaskSetting

lazy val a, b = project settings (Seq(myTaskSetting): _*)
```

I've no idea how to access the current configuration the task is bound to upon execution.

```
> myTask
project: axes
configuration: None
key: myTask
project: b
configuration: None
key: myTask
project: a
configuration: None
key: myTask
```